Looking for an Increasing Sequence $ \Lambda(n) $
I’m trying to find an increasing sequence $ \Lambda(n) $ of real numbers that satisfies the following conditions:

$ \Lambda(n) $ is strictly increasing.
There exists a $ c \geq 1 $ such that for all $ j \geq n $, we have
$$ 
   \Lambda(j) \leq c \Lambda(n) 
   $$


Attempt1: The sequence is defined as:
$$
\Lambda(n) = n
$$
This is a simple, linearly increasing sequence.
However, according to my supervisor's comment, this example is problematic. If we use the condition:
$$
\Lambda(j) \leq c \Lambda(n) \quad \text{for} \quad j \geq n,
$$
then the constant $c$ would satisfy:
$$
c \geq \frac{j}{n}.
$$
As $j \to \infty$, $c$ tends to infinity, which violates the requirement that $c$ must remain bounded.

An UPDATE


Attempt2: Consider the sequence:
$$
\Lambda(n) = 1 - \frac{1}{n}
$$
This sequence grows slowly and is bounded above by 1.
We want to verify that for $j \geq n$, there exists a constant $c \geq 1$ such that:
$$
\Lambda(j) \leq c \Lambda(n).
$$
Substituting the values of $\Lambda(j)$ and $\Lambda(n)$, we get:
$$
1 - \frac{1}{j} \leq c \left( 1 - \frac{1}{n} \right).
$$
Dividing both sides by $1 - \frac{1}{n}$:
$$
\frac{1 - \frac{1}{j}}{1 - \frac{1}{n}} = \frac{(j - 1)n}{j(n - 1)} \leq c.
$$
As $j \to \infty$, $$
   \frac{j - 1}{j} = 1 - \frac{1}{j}.
   $$
As $ j \to \infty $, the term $ \frac{1}{j} \to 0 $, so:
$$
   \frac{j - 1}{j} \to 1.
   $$
So, the expression $\left(\frac{(j - 1)n}{j(n - 1)}\right)$ is bounded, meaning that $c$ remains bounded.


Any suggestions or insights on constructing a sequence that satisfies these conditions would be greatly appreciated!

What kind of numbers are in your sequence?  Reals, naturals, or what?  Is the sequence strictly increasing, or could two numbers in a row be the same?

Added to the question

Be careful about the order of quantifiers. The condition “for all $j ≥ n$, there exists $c ≥ 1$ such that $Λ(j) ≤ c Λ(n)$” is trivially always satisfied as soon as $Λ(n) ≠ 0$ (just take $c = Λ(k)/Λ(n)$). You probably mean that there exists $c ≥ 1$ such that for all $j ≥ n$, we have $Λ(j) ≤ c Λ(n)$.

For that, you could try a sequence which grows slowly. For example, look at what happens when the sequence is bounded.

@JeanAbouSamra Could you write more details please?

@JeanAbouSamra Please have a look at the update I wrote

The update fails because of the detail that $\Lambda(1)=0$ so you cannot divide by $1-\frac 1j$ and there is no $c$ that works for $\Lambda(j) \ge c\Lambda(0)$  That is why I used the interval $[1,2]$.  As long as you are bounded away from zero and above, you can divide the maximum value by the minimum value to get $c$.

@RossMillikan What if I need $j$ tends to infinity, you example still works, right?

Yes, it does.  A $c$ of $2.1$ will make any number in my range greater than any other number.  As I said, any bounded range that is bounded away from $0$ will work as there will be a ratio that you can compute between the largest and smallest numbers.  Then take $c$ larger than that ratio.  This is why it was critical that the numbers be reals.  You cannot have an infinite increasing sequence of naturals in a bounded interval.

For real numbers you can do this.  You can find a strictly increasing sequence within a bounded interval, say $[1,2]$.    A simple example is $\Lambda(n)=2-\frac 1n$.  Then $c=2$ will work.

What happens if we work outside of a bounded interval?

Please have a look at the update I wrote
